# mmap with file descriptor -1 in disassembled output

Tags: ghidra

I am reversing a binary using Ghidra. In the disassembled output, I have the following lines in the main function:

```
(code *)mmap((void *)0x0,0x55,7,0x22,-1,0)
```

I am quite confused here since the file descriptor appears to be -1 and I remember reading that file descriptors should be non-negative.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Relevant section pertaining to the `flags` argument (emphasis added):

> MAP_ANONYMOUS:
> The mapping is not backed by any file; its contents are
> initialized to zero. **The fd argument is ignored; however,
> some implementations require fd to be -1 if MAP_ANONYMOUS (or
> MAP_ANON) is specified, and portable applications should
> ensure this.**  The offset argument should be zero.  The use of
> MAP_ANONYMOUS in conjunction with MAP_SHARED is supported on
> Linux only since kernel 2.4.

While this seems like a likely explanation, it isn't a 100% guarantee on its own. You could find further proof by looking at the headers for the system you're REing to confirm that `MAP_ANONYMOUS` is indeed being used as part of the flags.

Comment: Yes, what you are saying is true. It took me a while and help from another person to realize this. Thank you :)